# Custom run script error in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, bash, xcodebuild, xcode4.3

I'm trying to write a custom script as a separate build step in Xcode. To do that I've created Run script build phase. However I receive an error on this simple line (that's all I have in my script):

```
INCLUDE_PATH = $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/include
```

Error is

> ...Script-50117A74154B5E6100C6297E.sh: line 6: INCLUDE_PATH: command
>   not found Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127

Answer (score 0):

Found that! There should not be any spaces in a variable declaration.

```
INCLUDE_PATH=$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/include
```